# Running a Spring MVC application in Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I want to test a REST Web Service I created in spring using Tomcat 8. Before I proceed I want to verify that I can run MVC applications in Tomcat, but I am having problems; in STS the application is called as "http://localhost:8080/mvc/". I exported a war file and deployed it in Tomcat (I can even see it in the webapps folder), but I am getting a 404 Error. I did some modifications; I added

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

to pom.xml.
The web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I find it interesting that in STS it works with "http://localhost:8080/mvc/", although the servlet-name is appServlet; I also tried with appServlet but got the same error.

Comment: What URL are you getting the 404 error for?

Comment: STS is an IDE, not an app server. Where do you deploy your app when running it from STS? My guess is that it's Tomcat. What is the name of your war file?

Comment: In tomcat 6 I remember about a configuration file where you need to specify your hostname configuration with params like `autoDeploy="true"` etc. I do not know about tomcat 8, but big chances are you must do that inside your container, or find required options to configure it from your maven plugin directly.

Comment: hmm ok with your maven plugin you can't handle that directly, consider using the cargo plugin https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html

Answer (score -1):

did you create appServlet-servlet.xml in you web-inf directory?

Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory

By the way, if you want to create a test project of Restful Web Service, you can simply google "Spring Rest Maven hibernate sample", you will be given bunch of sample reference and zip files.